# Amazon S3 Gem for Rails 2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, rubygems

Which Amazon s3 gem is compatible with Rails 2.3 ?
It needs to be compatible with the Paperclip gem too.

Comment: Are aws-s3 or right_aws both compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'ved used this with rails 2.3.5 and paperclip:

```
config.gem "aws-s3", :lib => "aws/s3"
config.gem "paperclip"
```

in your .gems file:

```
aws-s3
paperclip
```

Answer (score 1):

Paperclip [supports S3 natively](http://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/storage.rb). [Here is formatted documentation](http://yardoc.org/docs/JasonKing-paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3) for that module. It uses the [aws/s3](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/) library for s3 access that you can use also. For direct access.

Comment: Paperclip based on **aws-sdk** now, you can use it